# C++ to C#: Pointers & Arrays

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, pointers

Below is a Win32 Console App procedure that demonstrates the dependence of various pointers on an array.  A change to the values in the original array (model) by for example uncommenting the lines marked '// uncomment ...' results in a change to the output.  My question is how do I get or mimic this behaviour in a C# managed code environment (i.e. without using unsafe and pointers)?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    float model[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { model[i] = i; }

    // uncomment these to alter the results
    //model[5] = 5000;
    //model[20] = 20000;
    //model[38] = 38000;

    static const int componentCount = 5;

    float* coefs = model;                   // coefs points to model[0]
    float* mean = coefs + componentCount;   // mean points to model[0 + componentCount] == model[5]
    float* cov = mean + 3*componentCount;   // cov points to model[0 + componentCount + 3*componentCount] == model[20] 

    int ci = 2;
    float* c = cov + 9*ci;  // c points to model[0 + componentCount + 3*componentCount + 9*ci] == model[38] 

    int i = 0;
    cout <<"model : "<< model[i] << endl;   // 0
    cout <<"coefs : "<< coefs[i] << endl;   // 0
    cout <<"mean  : "<< mean[i] << endl;    // 5 (or 5000)
    cout <<"cov   : "<< cov[i] << endl;     // 20 (or 20000)
    cout <<"ci    : "<< ci << endl;         // 2
    cout <<"c     : "<< c[i] << endl;       // 38 (or 38000)

cin.get(); }
```

Comment: Did you mean to dereference your pointers by using the array syntax, or is there a situation where you'd like i to be > 0 (meaning a value past the mean or something?)

Comment: By the way, what you're doing is called "pointer aliasing".

Comment: i could be something other than 0, it's just for the example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do the same thing in C# without unsafe code:

```
struct ArrayPointer<T>
{
    private T[] array;
    private int offset;
    public ArrayPointer(T[] array) : this(array, 0)
    {
    }
    private ArrayPointer(T[] array, int offset)
    {
        Debug.Assert(array != null);
        Debug.Assert(offset >= 0);
        Debug.Assert(offset < array.Length);
        this.array = array;
        this.offset = offset;
    }
    public static ArrayPointer<T> operator+(ArrayPointer<T> p1, int p2)
    {
        return new ArrayPointer<T>(p1.array, p1.offset + p2);
    }
```

And so on. Define operators for addition, subtraction, increment, decrement, comparison, indexing, conversion from arrays, and so on. Then you can say:

```
int[] arr = whatever;
ArrayPointer<int> pointer = arr;
pointer+=2;
pointer--;
int x = pointer[3];
```

and so on.

This approach has a lot of nice properties. For example, you can do a debug assert if you ever compare p1 > p2 when p1 and p2 are pointers to the interiors of different arrays. That is almost always a bug in C, but a hard one to catch.

Comment: This looks promising but when I try it I get a 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[]' to 'ArrayPointer<int>' error.

Comment: @descf: Did you read the paragraph where I said "and so on: define conversion operator from arrays"? This is not a complete solution, this is a sketch of a solution.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I have got as far as: ArrayPointer<int> pointer = new ArrayPointer<int>(arr); but to get to, for example: int x = pointer[n]; I have to write a method to return the value at that index.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a class that represents an array with some offset, similar to the one below. Additionaly, you might want it to implement `ICollection<T>` or at least `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
class ArrayWithOffset<T>
{
  T[] m_array;
  int m_offset;

  public ArrayWithOffset(T[] array, int offset)
  {
    m_array = array;
    m_offset = offset;
  }

  public T this[int i]
  {
    return m_array[offset + i]
  }
}
```

Comment: Great minds think alike. :-)  I would be inclined to make this a struct because it is small and can be used as a value in an algebraic system.

Comment: @Eric, when you said ".. can be used as a value in an algebraic system", what did you mean?

Comment: @Matt: You can make an algebraic system where array pointers can be added and subtracted similarly to how numbers are added and subtracted. An array pointer plus an int is another array pointer. An array pointer minus an array pointer is an int. And so on. When a thing is logically a *value* then it makes sense to model it as a *value type*.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of one parameter, pointer to array item, use pair of parameters (array, offset).